# Почему при попытке запуска программы выскакивает ошибка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При попытке запуске программы выскакивает данная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Bots_Telegram\Telegramm\BUDDY.py", line 141, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\ryzhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 618, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\ryzhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\ryzhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 640, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\ryzhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 143, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\ryzhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 89, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: callback_inline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'call'
```

Код:

```
# coding: utf-8
import types


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import telebot
    import config
    import tg_analytic
    from telebot import types
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

count = 0

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    username = message.from_user.first_name
    tg_analytic.statistics(message.chat.id, message.text)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Привет, "
        + str(username)
        + "! На связи  IT Buddy бот МТС Банка. Очень рад с тобой познакомиться. (картинка Панда кодит)  Сегодня проведу для тебя квиз по Java, frontend и UX дизайну. Выбери направление, набери 4 балла и получи приз. Поехали!",
    )
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Java разработка", callback_data = "0")
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Frontend разработка", callback_data = "1")
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("UX дизайн", callback_data = "2")
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Текст: выбери направление",
        reply_markup=markup,
    )


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text(message):
    tg_analytic.statistics(message.chat.id, message.text)
    if message.text[:10] == "статистика" or message.text[:10] == "Статистика":
        st = message.text.split(" ")
        if "txt" in st or "тхт" in st:
            tg_analytic.analysis(st, message.chat.id)
            with open("%s.txt" % message.chat.id, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
                tg_analytic.remove(message.chat.id)
        else:
            messages = tg_analytic.analysis(st, message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messages)
    else:
        tg_analytic.statistics(message.chat.id, message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ой, ой... Я тебя не понял. ")
        bot.send_sticker(
            message.chat.id,
            "CAACAgIAAxkBAAIP4F92EYCC4n5T7uepsto0eIO_EAABqwACBAADll-TFeM60_pUapUTGwQ",
        )
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            "Я обязательно ✍️ передам моим создателям твой запрос и смогу в будущем лучше тебя понимать. "
            + "\n"
            + "\n"
            + "Чтобы продолжить разговор, нажми на серые кнопки выше.",
        )

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(count, call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "0":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Верно", callback_data = "3")
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Неверно", callback_data = "4")
            markup.add(item1, item2)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Отлично! Всего 10 вопросов, ответь верно на 4 из них и получи приз."
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Вопрос 1: При возникновении любого исключения JVM гарантированно сгенерирует стек-трейс."
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Для выбора варианта нажми на цифру. ",
                reply_markup=markup,
            )
        elif call.data == "4":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            count += 1
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дальше?", callback_data = "5")
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Верно! Твои очки: " + str(count),
                reply_markup=markup,
            )
        elif call.data == "3":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дальше?", callback_data = "5")
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Неверно! Твои очки: " + str(count),
                reply_markup=markup,
            )
        elif call.data == "5":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Верно", callback_data = "6")
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Неверно", callback_data = "7")
            markup.add(item1, item2)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Вопрос 2: Entity class не может быть абстрактным.",
                reply_markup=markup,
            )
        elif call.data == "7":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            count += 1
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дальше?", callback_data = "8")
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Верно! Твои очки: " + str(count),
                reply_markup=markup,
            )
        elif call.data == "6":
            tg_analytic.statistics(call.message.chat.id, call.message.text)
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дальше?", callback_data = "8")
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(
                call.message.chat.id,
                "Неверно! Твои очки: " + str(count),
                reply_markup=markup,
            )


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Думаю, ошибка возникает из-за передачи переменной `count` в функцию `def callback_inline(count, call):`, вопрос: почему?

Comment: не понимаю подобные вопросы: "ошибка возникает из-за передачи переменной count в функцию, почему?" -  а чего не хватает в ответе: " callback_inline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'call'"? Да и сам вызов в приведённом  коде не вижу - как вам  отвечать должны?

Comment: Сергей, это код Telegram бота, функция def callback_inline(count, call): вызывается, когда пользователь отправляет боту сообщение. Проблема в том, что обычно в нее передается только аргумент call, но мне нужно передать еще и аргумент count и при попытке это сделать выскакивает приведенная в вопросе ошибка.

Comment: Я не понимаю ответ. Он не отвечает на мои вопросы. Я вообще боты не писал, но не думаю, что это сильно важно в данном контексте. Упрощу: 1) О чём именно, по-вашему, говорит ошибка? 2) Дополнительно: что это значит: "обычно в нее передается только аргумент call", когда у функции `def callback_inline(count, call)`  есть два обязательных аргумента? 3) В ботах отсутствут код? Почему на мой комментарий "вызов в коде не вижу" вы вместо добавления кода начинаете мне о нём рассказывать?

Comment: Это может показаться невежливым, но раз вы не писали ботов, можете и на вопрос не отвечать. Он был задан тем, кто занимался написанием ботов. Извините, если задел.

Comment: Ну, дождемся ответа. Надеюсь. Буду сильно удивлён, если общие правила языка и подход к отладке вдруг перестают действовать в этой области. Тем не менее, интересно, что нет ответа ни на один вопрос. А не зная области, кстати, я тут достаточно часто верно отвечал, так как общее превалирует над частным. "Извините, если задел.":-)

Comment: Сергей, благодарю за попытки оказания помощи, но я и сам разобрался. Нужно было первой строчкой функции написать  global count.